# Dynamic loading of a view partial using codeigniter and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, codeigniter

I'm making a single page application using code igniter and jquery, so the master page contains the upper part of html including the css etc.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>BGC</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url().'assets/css/fontawesome.min.css';?>">
    <!-- other css here -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
     <div id="main-section">

     </div>
```

and then a footer page to include the lower part of the html

```html
<script>
    var BASE = "<?php echo site_url(); ?>";
</script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url().'assets/js/jquery.js';?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- other js scripts here -->
    
</body>

</html>
```

so the div main-section is where i would insert dynamic pages using jquery and codeigniter view.. the problem is when i try to fetch and load it to the container, the js and css are getting corrupted but no errors are being thrown.

i fetch them from CI in this way

```
public function shop() {

    $this->load->view('display/shop');
}
```

and using jquery like this, ajax request

```
JQ("#btnshop").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    JQ.ajax({
        url: BASE + "/display/home/shop",
        data: {},
        success: function(result) {
            JQ("#main-section").html(result);
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

the #shop is the id of the navigation button, which i did not include in here. thanks in advance for any ideas how work it around

Answer (score 0):

Try below code it should work.

```
   echo $this->load->view('display/shop',TRUE);
```

Comment: just cross check stylesheets link tag and call js sript file in header not on footer